# Shell script with a for loop and an “array”

Tags: bash, shell, array, for, bash-array

How can I use this shell script with for loop and an array.
I would like to call create condition for quality gate creation of sonarqube with a for loop. Example:

```
#!/bin/bash --login

echo "Creating SonarQube Gateway Condition"

QG_ID=$(cat qualitygate.json | jq -r ".id")
Gateway="curl -u ${USERNAME}:${PASSWORD} -k -X POST "${SONAR_HOST_URL}/api/qualitygates/create_condition?"
declare -a gateMetrics=("gateId=$QG_ID&metric=coverage&op=LT&error=80\"" "gateId=$QG_ID&metric=duplicated_lines_density&op=GT&error=10\"")

for val in "${gateMetrics[@]}"
do
  echo $Gateway$val
done
```

I want the output as below after running above command

```
curl -u ${USERNAME}:${PASSWORD} -k -X POST "${SONAR_HOST_URL}/api/qualitygates/create_condition?gateId=$QG_ID&metric=coverage&op=LT&error=80"
```

Comment: There is a quoting issue with:
Gateway="curl -u ${USERNAME}:${PASSWORD} -k -X POST 
"${SONAR_HOST_URL}/api/qualitygates/create_condition?".
Use:

Gateway="curl -u ${USERNAME}:${PASSWORD} -k -X POST 
\"${SONAR_HOST_URL}/api/qualitygates/create_condition?\""

Comment: Have your run it through `shellcheck`?

Comment: Can you help me

Comment: In your gateMetrics, why is there a one escaped double quote? Where's the matching double quote?

Comment: The other escaped double quote should be in $Gateway (see my answer below) right after "POST".

Comment: Without seeing `$USERNAME` and `$PASSWORD` it's hard to know whether their contents interfere with later parsing.  I'd be inclined not to expand them until much later.

Answer (score 1):

You could break it down into smaller pieces.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash --login

echo "Creating SonarQube Gateway Condition"

curl_cmd=( curl -u "${USERNAME}:${PASSWORD}" -k -X POST )
url="${SONAR_HOST_URL}/api/qualitygates/create_condition"
qg_id=$( jq -r ".id" qualitygate.json )
gateMetrics=(
    coverage,LT,80
    duplicated_lines_density,GT,10
)
query_fmt="gateId=%s&metric=%s&op=%s&error=%s"

for metric in "${gateMetrics[@]}"; do
    IFS=, read -r m o e <<< "$metric"
    printf -v query "$query_fmt" "$qg_id" "$m" "$o" "$e"

    # remove this echo if it looks OK
    echo "${curl_cmd[@]}" "${url}?${query}"
done
```

You'll also want to read [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: Error at :  curl -u ****:**** -k -X POST: not found

Comment: Did you use the `curl_cmd` array like I did, or did you use a string? Read the link I posted

Comment: I used it in the same way you shared and it failed due to "curl -u ****:**** -k -X POST: not found " at curl_cmd step only

Comment: You must have added quotes somewhere, or did not declare "curl_cmd" as an array. The method I use in my answer will not try to run curl and its arguments concatenated together as a single program name. Check again

Comment: Hi, I copied the same thing which you shared and found syntax error as .......script.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Comment: That means you are executing the script with `sh` not `bash`

Comment: Yes i made the changes now.. But it is not coming as...curl -u ${USERNAME}:${PASSWORD} -k -X POST "${SONAR_HOST_URL}/api/qualitygates/create_condition?gateId=$QG_ID&metric=coverage&op=LT&error=80"



I am getting spaces in between. Can you please help

Comment: Getting spaces after create_condition?.........

curl -u ****:**** -k -X POST http://sonar.ethan.svc.cluster.local:9001/sonar/api/qualitygates/create_condition?gateId=AXdkH2IK_gphtTomeXio&metric=duplicated_lines_density&op=GT&error=10

Answer (score 0):

Variables for USERNAME; PASSWORD and QG_ID added for a self running example:

```
#!/bin/bash --login

USERNAME=foo
PASSWORD=bar
SONAR_HOST_URL="https://sonar.example.com"

echo "Creating SonarQube Gateway Condition"

# QG_ID=$(cat qualitygate.json | jq -r ".id")
QG_ID=123456

Gateway="curl -u ${USERNAME}:${PASSWORD} -k -X POST \"${SONAR_HOST_URL}/api/qualitygates/create_condition?"
declare -a gateMetrics=("gateId=$QG_ID&metric=coverage&op=LT&error=80\"" "gateId=$QG_ID&metric=duplicated_lines_density&op=GT&error=10\"")

for val in "${gateMetrics[@]}"; do
  echo "$Gateway$val"
done
```

Output:

```
Creating SonarQube Gateway Condition
curl -u foo:bar -k -X POST "https://sonar.example.com/api/qualitygates/create_condition?gateId=123456&metric=coverage&op=LT&error=80"
curl -u foo:bar -k -X POST "https://sonar.example.com/api/qualitygates/create_condition?gateId=123456&metric=duplicated_lines_density&op=GT&error=10"
```

Comment: I already tried this and got below error ---Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string at Gateway="curl -u ${USERNAME}:${PASSWORD} -k -X POST \"${SONAR_HOST_URL}/api/qualitygates/create_condition?"